# JDBC or JPA for NoSQL

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, jdbc, nosql

I am currently working with MongoDB in Java and do not want to use the mongo-java driver which is very time consuming to code and also hard to maintain.
I thought developing my own mongo-JDBC driver (since the one available is commercial). Am I on the right track.?

```
Also should I use some framework instead of pure jdbc .?
```

```
I am not sure about such frameworks for NoSQL databases. Kindly guide?
```

Comment: Why don't you make use of spring-data-mongodb? http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/

Comment: ElasticSearch is the easiest and fastest nosql option, imo.

Comment: This is not the site for recommendations. It is for problems.

Comment: There is no need to downvote this. I just wanted a clear idea on using frameworks over jdbc. I only care about performance and ease of use for others who might use it in future

Comment: Anyway thank you.....more insights are always welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring JDBC instead of pure JDBC and Spring Data MongoDB for MongoDB. They are quite easy to use.

Comment: It seems that Spring Data MongoDB does use [mongodb-driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver) -- which looks like the driver OP don't want to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Kundera is no longer maintained

---

You can use [Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera) for this. It's an **open-source object mapper for NoSQL databases** supporting MongoDB, Cassandra, HBase, ONS, etc. It takes query in JPA format.

Comment: But it would require other developers to learn jpql (what if it is similar to sql)

Comment: yes you need to know  JPQL or SQL as JPQL is quite similar to SQL.